# What is 'p' and 'g' in ArgoCD policy.csv?

Tags: kubernetes, argocd

I'm trying to configure RBAC for argocd, I saw a lot of examples like this one below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: argocd-rbac-cm
  namespace: argocd
data:
  policy.default: role:readonly
  policy.csv: |
    p, role:org-admin, applications, *, */*, allow
    p, role:org-admin, clusters, get, *, allow
    p, role:org-admin, repositories, get, *, allow
    p, role:org-admin, repositories, create, *, allow
    p, role:org-admin, repositories, update, *, allow
    p, role:org-admin, repositories, delete, *, allow
    p, role:org-admin, logs, get, *, allow
    p, role:org-admin, exec, create, */*, allow

    g, your-github-org:your-team, role:org-admin
```

In the first column you either have the `g` or `p` letters.
Tried searching for the definition on [ArgoCD Documentation](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/rbac/#:%7E:text=The%20RBAC%20feature%20enables%20restriction,or%20more%20local%20users%20setup.), but either they don't mention it or I just failed to see it.

So what does this `p` and `g` stand for?

Comment: On a related note, what exactly is `your-github-org` referring to? A domain? I'm trying to set this up with GitLab and trying to figure the right syntax. I'm also assuming for GitLab `your-team` would be a GitLab Group name. Any ideas or clarification? Am I thinking about this all wrong?

Comment: @tubensandwich I'm sorry, I haven't looked at this in a while and now it looks like Chinese to me.  The "github-org" in this instance is a reference to an entity on github called "Organization" - sort of like a private space which you can create for your organization. I'm not sure what is the equivalent on Gitlab or if it's even compatible.

Comment: Alex, No worries, I was mainly trying this approach because I couldn't get self-signed certificates working with the dex config (so I was trying general oidc config). I was able to get certs working with a workaround mentioned at https://github.com/dexidp/dex/issues/1542#issuecomment-1602506504, in which case the policy groups was straight forward. Thanks.

Comment: > what exactly is `your-github-org`?  See this documentation: 

https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/user-management/#dex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess p=Permission, g=Group.
p is what permission the role have.
g is which role this group have

Answer (score 0):

In the [RBAC Configuration documentation](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/rbac/#rbac-configuration), under [The extensions Resource](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/rbac/#the-extensions-resource) section, look under **Explanation**. Line 1 which begins with `g` states that this defines a **group**. Lines 2 and 3 which begin with `p` state that they each define a **policy**.

Answer (score 0):

ArgoCD uses [casbin](https://casbin.org/docs/syntax-for-models) under the hood.

Here's the model configuration for ArgoCD: [model.conf](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/blob/master/assets/model.conf).

It's used in the [rbac.go file](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/blob/master/util/rbac/rbac.go).

Briefly, `p` is used to define policies and `g` is used to define roles (or groups in ArgoCD terms).